# How to remove all references from a Dialog on dismiss in Xamarin.Android (potential memory leak)?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, xamarin.android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I guess I have a memory leak because after I open a specific `Dialog` and change to a new `Activity`, the app crashes without any warning and Visual Studio/App stops without any warning or specific line where it happens as you can see in the animated gif:

[image: preview1]

This second animated gif is where I'm debugging the app in Visual Studio and then suddenly stops. The app finished in line that doesn't make sense `base.OnDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset)`:

[image: preview 2]

Now, the Dialog, is quite heavy because it does some mathematical calculations in real-time:

**Dialog:**

```
private void BtnCompareAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GravityPlanets gInfo = new();
    View dialogView = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.CompareAll, null);
    var Dialog = new Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder(Context);

    int firstCelestialLoc = GetItemPosition(planets, SpinnerFirstCelestial.Text);
    var gravity = new Supernova.Core.Gravity();

    var listView = dialogView.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.lstCelestialObjects);
    var textObject1 = dialogView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textObject1);
    var imgView = dialogView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imgCObject);
    var yourWeight = dialogView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.yourWeight);

    imgView.SetImageDrawable(compareAllList[firstCelestialLoc].image);

    textObject1.Text = SpinnerGravityUnits.Text == gUnits[0]
        ? $"{planets[firstCelestialLoc]}, {GetCelestialObject(gInfo.CelestialObjectType(firstCelestialLoc))}, {gInfo.GetGravity(firstCelestialLoc)} {SpinnerGravityUnits.Text}"
        : $"{planets[firstCelestialLoc]}, {GetCelestialObject(gInfo.CelestialObjectType(firstCelestialLoc))}, {Math.Round(gravity.ChangeToFeet(gInfo.GetGravity(firstCelestialLoc)), 3)} {SpinnerGravityUnits.Text}";

    List<DrawerData> currentObjects = compareAllList.DeepClone();
    currentObjects.RemoveAt(firstCelestialLoc);

    bool isNumeric = double.TryParse(TxtWeight.Text, out double earthWeight);
    if (isNumeric && earthWeight > 0)
    {
        yourWeight.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        yourWeight.Text = $"{GetString(Resource.String.lblYourWeight)} {TxtWeight.Text}{SpinnerWeightUnits.Text}";
    }
    else
    {
        yourWeight.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
        yourWeight.Text = "";
    }

    GravityPlanets gPlanets = new();

    for (int i = 0; i < currentObjects.Count(); i++)
    {
        var secondG = GetItemPosition(planets, currentObjects[i].name);
        var gPercentage = Math.Round(gInfo.PercentageGravity(firstCelestialLoc, secondG), 0);

        switch (gInfo.ComparedGravity(firstCelestialLoc, secondG))
        {
            case 0:
                gravType = GetString(Resource.String.gravLower);
                currentObjects[i].color = "#43A047";
                break;
            default:
                gravType = GetString(Resource.String.gravGreater);
                currentObjects[i].color = "#F44336";
                break;
        }

        var gravVal = SpinnerGravityUnits.Text == gUnits[0] ? gInfo.GetGravity(secondG) : Math.Round(gravity.ChangeToFeet(gInfo.GetGravity(secondG)), 3);

        currentObjects[i].name = $"<b>{currentObjects[i].name}, {GetCelestialObject(gInfo.CelestialObjectType(secondG))}</b><br>{gravVal} {SpinnerGravityUnits.Text}, {string.Format(gravType, gPercentage)}";

        if (isNumeric && earthWeight > 0)
        {
            currentObjects[i].name += $"<br>{GetString(Resource.String.lblYourWeightCO)} {GetNewWeight(gPlanets, double.Parse(TxtWeight.Text), firstCelestialLoc, secondG)} {SpinnerWeightUnits.Text}";
        }

        var adapter = new CompareAllAdapter(currentObjects);

        listView.Adapter = adapter;

        Dialog.SetView(dialogView);

        Dialog.SetOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener());

        Dialog.Show();
    }
}
```

And I use this class to "dispose" of the dialog:

**Dismiss class:**

```
private class OnDismissListener : Java.Lang.Object, IDialogInterfaceOnDismissListener
{
    public void OnDismiss(IDialogInterface dialog)
    {
        dialog.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Oddly, it seems it wasn't properly disposed of because I can open other dialogs and nothing happens, this is the only one that causes this abnormal behavior.

Additionally, I tried to remove its reference by making the dialog's value null while making it a **property** and failed. I also tried to use the garbage collector and also failed because it crashed the app.

I even tried avoiding to store any history using this in the `MainActivity` class:

`[Android.App.Activity(Label = "Gravity Now!", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/ic_icon", NoHistory = true)]`

I even created an additional `OnCancelListener` where I'm even disposing of the `DialogView` without any result:

```
Dialog.SetOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener(dialogView));

private class OnCancelListener : Java.Lang.Object, IDialogInterfaceOnCancelListener
{
    private View dialogView;

    public OnCancelListener(View dialogView)
    {
        this.dialogView = dialogView;
    }

    public void OnCancel(IDialogInterface dialog)
    {
        dialogView.Dispose();
        dialogView = null;
        dialog.Dispose();
        dialog = null;
    }
}
```

For more info, here is the full source code:

https://bitbucket.org/supernovaic/gnow-android/src/master/

Also, I got this crash file, but I cannot find anything useful:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/10-wmY337mG_k6ZoS7GAcFI1reR6eqQRy/view?usp=sharing

These are the last lines:

> 09-11 18:19:26.889 28140 31014 I ActivityManager: Force stopping
> tk.supernova.gnow appid=10156 user=0: from pid 13171 09-11
> 18:19:26.892 28785 28785 I AppBase : AppBase.onTrimMemory():615
> onTrimMemory(): 5 09-11 18:19:26.894 13171 13174 I cmd     : oneway
> function results will be dropped but finished with status OK and
> parcel size 4 09-11 18:19:26.935 28785 28785 I
> GoogleInputMethodService: GoogleInputMethodService.onTrimMemory():4225
> onTrimMemory(): 5 09-11 18:19:26.951 28140 28158 W ActivityManager:
> setHasOverlayUi called on unknown pid: 12844 09-11 18:19:26.953 28140
> 28158 W ActivityTaskManager: Activity top resumed state loss timeout
> for ActivityRecord{3c51759 u0
> tk.supernova.gnow/crc64c3564668e399e885.Help t-1 f}}

At this point, I don't know what else to do. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**P.S.:**

- **I have tested it on physical devices also (Oppo A91 and Nexus 7 - 2013).**
- Here is the link if you want to test the error in your physical device: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tk.supernova.gnow

**Update:**

I got this answer from another [forum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/548380/how-to-fully-dismiss-a-dialog-in-xamarinandroid.html#comment-569996):

> **LeonLu-MSFT**

> In the
> DefinitionFragment.cs file on line 36 in the `LoadGif()` function, you
> could try to use the `GetBuffer()` method in-place of the `ToArray()`
> method.
>
> Please refer to this document for further explanations:
> [MemoryStream.ToArray Method (System.IO) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream.toarray?view=net-5.0)

Now, it loads the help but crashes without a reason again between tabs. By the way, I changed to `GetBuffer()` in both tabs.

Comment: Which line of the code make the crash? Please check the code again whether you get the correct value or not. When you got this crash, do you get any exceptions? If yes, could you provide the details?

Comment: Hi @WendyZang-MSFT, as in the picture, it just crashes, there are no exceptions and stops Visual Studio by force. I got the crash file here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/10-wmY337mG_k6ZoS7GAcFI1reR6eqQRy/view?usp=sharing

Next which line? I'm not so sure (it stopped here in the Main: MDrawerLayout.CloseDrawers()) because I can open the help as many times as I want while I don't open the planets dialog. If I don't open it, then, I can open the help, as soon as I open the dialog and try to open the help then it crashes.

Comment: I have download the code sample to test. But there are some errors for me and i could not fix immediately. Could you check the MDrawerLayout in debug? Does it be null? Have you try to use `CloseDrawer` to close the specified drawer? Code: `MDrawerLayout.CloseDrawer(view);`

Comment: Hi @WendyZang-MSFT, I don't think the Drawer has any relationship, for the simple reason that I can open other Dialogs as in the gif and nothing happens. The help only crashes if I open that specific dialog not if I do anything else. The Dialog is somehow heavy and most likely there is a memory leak. If I try to run the GC it crashes the entire app. Also, VS doesn't show any warning.

Comment: Also @WendyZang-MSFT, Visual Studio stops after that line. I can literally just open the dialog and go to help and crashes. I go to help at any other moment and don't crash.

Comment: Hi @WendyZang-MSFT, I added an extra animated gif with the debugging in Visual Studio.

Comment: Hi @WendyZang-MSFT, I even tried `[Android.App.Activity(Label = "Gravity Now!", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/ic_icon", NoHistory = true)]` without any result.

Comment: Have you try to set the drawerView and slideOffset in OnDrawerSlide.  You could try to add a ActionBarDrawerEventArgs to set. Please check the code sample in the link below. https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Android-AppCompat/blob/master/ActionBarCompat/DrawerLayout/Helpers/MyActionBarDrawerToggle.cs

Comment: Hi @WendyZang-MSFT, but I'm sure that even if I comment that section is not going to work. I already tried skipping the section with the debugger moving the arrow and still stopped.

Comment: Hi @WendyZang-MSFT, there is something in the log like something is being destroyed and tried to be accessed: `.supernova.gno: JNI ERROR (app bug): accessed deleted Global 0x4216
.supernova.gno: java_vm_ext.cc:577] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: use of deleted global reference 0x4216
 .supernova.gno: java_vm_ext.cc:577]     from android.view.View crc64c3564668e399e885.DefinitionFragment.n_onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater, android.view.ViewGroup, android.os.Bundle)
.supernova.gno: runtime.cc:655] Runtime aborting...`

Comment: Normally, thie error caused by the invalidate value. Still need to debug the code to find which line make the app crash and check the invalidate value.

Comment: Hi @WendyZang-MSFT, I got this answer in another forum: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/548380/how-to-fully-dismiss-a-dialog-in-xamarinandroid.html?childToView=569996#comment-569996, now, it loads the first tab but crashes if I move between them. Any idea, why?

Comment: Glad that you have solved this issue. You could post a new thread with the steps to reproduce the crash.

Comment: Hi @WendyZang-MSFT, it's not really fixed because if you move between tabs crashes again and the situation is exactly the same one.

Comment: Hi @WendyZang-MSFT, here is the new log report:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/118DxagBgbK45LVH6R-QqtLUl5VVQ3ung/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi @WendyZang-MSFT, I found that there is a problem with this library https://www.nuget.org/packages/DeepCloner/. Somehow, when you do a deep clone, the references are not being removed. I had to re-create the logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the bug was here:

```
List<DrawerData> currentObjects = compareAllList.DeepClone();
```

I had to change the logic and create the temp data in a different way:

```
private List<DrawerData> GetPlanetsData()
{
    return new List<DrawerData>()
    {
        new DrawerData() {
            name = GetString(Resource.String.itemSun),
            image = GetCelestialObjectDrawable(Resource.Drawable.sun),
            url = GetString(Resource.String.itemWikiSun)
        },
        new DrawerData() {
            name = GetString(Resource.String.itemMercury),
            image = GetCelestialObjectDrawable(Resource.Drawable.mercury),
            url = GetString(Resource.String.itemWikiMercury)
        },
        new DrawerData() {
            name = GetString(Resource.String.itemVenus),
            image = GetCelestialObjectDrawable(Resource.Drawable.venus),
            url = GetString(Resource.String.itemWikiVenus)
        }
        //...
    };
}

List<DrawerData> currentObjects = GetPlanetsData();
```

It seems somehow the [Deep Cloner](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DeepCloner/) data created cannot be removed somehow.